# money_format, move the 'currency name'

Tags: php, currency, money-format

I'm at the moment using the [PHP `money_format()` function](http://php.net/money_format), and have `money_format('%.0i', $row['price'])` at the moment it outputs something like: **`DKK 199.900`** - is there a way I can  output it like **`199.900 DKK`** instead?

Comment: Just read the documentation on `money_format`: http://php.net/manual/de/function.money-format.php There it is explained in detail how to solve exactly your problem.

Comment: Basti, I can't find it sorry.

Comment: My bad. I see the problem is that `money_format` will output `DKK` before the number even in the `da_DK` locale. I don't see that you can tell `money_format` to place the currency symbol on a different position. I would use `number_format` and add the currency symbol manually like Ing did. Do you have the need to change the currency symbol depending on the locale or will it always be DKK?

Comment: It will always be DKK, for now at least!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `number_format` instead (this is cross OS compatible too):

```
$value = number_format($value, [decimal places]).' DKK';
```

Answer (score 1):

replace first argument of money_format to '%.0i DKK';

Comment: But, consider use `number_format` because `money_format` have compatibility issues.

Comment: `money_format('%.0i DKK', $number)` will output `string 'DKK 1.235 DKK' (length=13)` with `setlocale(LC_MONETARY, "da_DK");`.

Answer (score 0):

So the pattern `money_format('%!.0i DKK', $price);` could be a solution where `!` will put off auto currency sign and it is added manually at the end

Answer (score 0):

Actually @sandeep was right, he just forgot to add the `!` to remove the monetary symbol from the beginning.

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'da_DK');
$money_in_the_bank = 9333;
echo money_format('%!.0i DKK', $money_in_the_bank);
```

This will output:

`9.333 DKK`